# How to frequently Update all the documents with a random number in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I have created the following schema in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52d5c71be4b0a5cd12da5e8b"),
    "edges" : [
        {
            "edge_id" : "0",
            "dst" : NumberLong(1),
            "score" : ***Numeric Value***

        },
        {
            "edge_id" : "1",
            "dst" : NumberLong(6),
            "score" : ***Numeric Value***

        }
    ],
    "src" : NumberLong(0)
}
```

The above MongoDB collection has millions of records. My requirement is:

1. Update the `Score` field with the random numeric value.
2. All the updates should complete in few seconds (1–10 secs.).
3. Run the above update procedure infinitely.

I would like to perform the above task either using MongoDB or using a combination of MongoDB and Java.

What is the best way to perform the above task?

Comment: I have generated millions random numbers using XORShift random number generator(JAVA Code) and inserted into another mongodb collection named(randomNumbers). Now the problem is how to push these numbers from one collection to other efficiently...? The generation and loading those number to collection took 1 sec..

Comment: Best way to "push them to another collection" is MapReduce.

Comment: BTW, you can't update million records in 10 seconds. If you don't shard this records across hundred of machines of course.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how to do that..I have created random schema as : {timestamp:"",values:[1,2,3,.....millions]}

Comment: You're probably better off using the MongoDB Java driver to insert them into the correct collection to begin with - generating them, inserting them and then moving them sounds really inefficient.

Comment: Yes you are correct for the same I have partitioned the whole data into different machines and now I want to do the above things for single partition. Same I will apply to all the partition. Hope this task will complete in few seconds.

Comment: Yes Trisha, It seems inefficient however I missed one requirement that I also want this data as persistent data. Hence I have to store it in two different collection. In my design the data stored in random collection will act as a persistent data.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve .. is this some sort of load testing idea?

Comment: @Stennie: No Stennie, I would like to simulate some real life problem in which the edge weights of Graph changes frequently(in seconds)..

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in MongoDB currently to `update` a batch of documents at a single time. You can `update` multiple documents with the same value only. So, you'd need to, for each document, individually set the `score` field. Also, you apparently have an array, so, you'd need to update using the positional array notation the specific `score` field (or set the entire array).

**This will not complete in seconds**. It's simply too much activity (disk and network).

If you explained more of what your trying to accomplish with this update, then there may be a better solution. Given the frequency of updates and the fact that the data is constantly changing, I'd suggest that this data structure only be kept in memory for example, and possibly served to "clients" via a web service or other transfer mechanism.

**Update:**

Given your requirements, I'd suggest that this is not a good fit for MongoDB (or maybe for any disk-backed database for that matter).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me explain the requirements in details. I have graph data which have millions of nodes and edges. For the same I have created the above schema(Schema in original question). Now I have partitioned this data into several partitions (using some mechanism) and stored into different mongodb database servers. Now I would like to create a real time simulator which will provide the "score" as a edge weight random values between 0-1000 for each of the edge. This simulator should store this "score" value to some persistent collection(random) and also in the graph collection.

Comment: My application is going to use persistent data for some statistical analysis(For that it will need all historical data "score value") and graph data to evaluate the real time shortest path between two nodes in the graph.

Comment: Given that, I've edited my answer to suggest that this doesn't seem like a good match for MongoDB. Even sharded this would be a LOT of activity to match your requirements. And then in the end, most of the (disk) work would be wasted as the data changes so frequently.

Comment: Can we write a script like "PL/SQL" in mongodb which can do all the simulator task in the mongodb database itself like generation of random numbers and move them from one collection to other. The above requirement seems inefficient to solve using memory based database because it have to deal with large data that's why I chose mongodb(disk based)

Comment: No. There's no scripting language that would make this more efficient. Millions of small documents as you're suggesting should easily fit in RAM, shouldn't they?

Comment: Actually I would like to use commodity hardware(low RAM) to deploy this application. I am not able to dedicate whole machines RAM to the database as there are others things will be working on the same time. That's why I don't think that in memory database is a solution for my requirement. One more problem with in memory database is scalability issue...

Comment: If an in-memory solution can't do this, a disk solution won't work. Disk costs more than RAM. How many actual documents are you storing? What's the working set? To even have a chance of this performing well, you'll need to have enough memory to hold the ENTIRE working set, which essentially is the entire collection.

Comment: Working set consist of millions of documents per partition. Actually, that is the problem we have to solve using bigdata. We can compromise with the cast as we do not any other thing to compromise(better machines). I do not bother about the time required to solve the above problem, what I need is a correct solution.

Comment: I am agree with your thoughts. Can you suggest any distributed in memory database to achieve the above goal?

Answer (score 0):

With mongodb, we can update multiple documents by  (for example)

```
db.getCollection('users').update({
    username: {$eq: null}
}, {
    $set: {
            username: 'not_set_yet'
    }
}, {
    multi: true
})
```

If you use `Typegoose` or `mongoose` then you can add a `pre` hook to listen the `update` event, for example in `typegoose`:

```js
import {pre} from 'typegoose'

@pre<User>('save', function(next: HookNextFunction) {
  // Caution! Do not use arrow function here, otherwise the `this` variable would // be point to global instead of
  // this model !
  this.username = this.username === 'not_set_yet' ? generateARandomUserName() : this.username

  next()
})
```

So by combining the 2 things:

- set `multi` to true in the update statement
- set a `update` hook

it suppose to work so that worth a try.